# How to crawl a website by using a link that paste into a placeholder and it is triggered by a submit button

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra, nokogiri, placeholder

I am using Ruby,Sinatra and nokogiri. I can crawl my desired website by using get post method (lunching the application: shotgun xy.rb or ruby.rb)
However I want to get the result in a different way: Get the url link, paste it to a place holder and then click "submit".

I cannot find out how it is possible.
Here are the essential codes:

```
    player = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.transfermarkt.de/marcelo/profil/spieler/44501'))
    @team = player.css('.dataZusatzDaten').css('.hauptpunkt').text
    @number = player.css('.dataHeader').css('.dataRN').text
```

More codes of my failed try:
Ruby:

```
    post '/result' do
    player = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.transfermarkt.de/marcelo/profil/spieler/44501'))
    @team = player.css('.dataZusatzDaten').css('.hauptpunkt').text
    @number = player.css('.dataHeader').css('.dataRN').text
    erb :playersresult, :locals => { other: whatever }
    end
```

HTML:

[Pic of the Placeholder page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT4uf.png)

HTML:
[Result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1z9a.png)

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you need some interaction with the target website as part of your parsing process, consider using Capybara/Watir - it will make your life easier.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages along with "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Pictures of code and data do us very little good when trying to debug code. These help explain: "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
"[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"